# reading unopened mail from office365 in python using REST API

Tags: python, rest, exchangewebservices, office365

How can I obtain all unopened mail (metadata and content including attachments) from office365 in python (v2.6) using a REST request?  The commented page value is returning **urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request**, while the uncommented page value works fine.  Thanks!

```
import urllib
import urllib2

#page = 'https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Inbox/Messages?$filter=IsRead'
page = 'https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Inbox/Messages'
username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"

p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
p.add_password(realm='', uri=page, user=username, passwd=password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

response = urllib2.urlopen(page)
print(response.read())
```

Comment: correct page variable is: 'https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Inbox/Messages?$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false'.  Thanks again MrPiao for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EWS via SOAP to get this information, but creating SOAP requests is going to be more complicated than using the new Office 365 REST APIs, especially from Python.

See this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605901(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605901%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

So, in order to get all the unread email from your inbox, you would make a request like (not tested):

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Inbox/Messages?$filter=IsRead eq false HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full
```

If you insist on using vanilla EWS, you can use the FindItem operation.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566107(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566107%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  Now, would you happen to know how I would pass the suggested parameters "eq false HTTP/1.1" in my code above?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but eq false is part of the query string and HTTP/1.1 just means you're making a HTTP 1.1 request :)